# Adding short CRS description to composer template?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, print-composer

How can I add CRS description as automated text for composer template? so anytime someone open a project, it uses the project CRS to print description of CRS like: WGS84 / Mercator 1

`@project_crs` gives me ESPG code, `@project_crs_definition` gives me more than I want in a different format I want.

All I want is simply WGS84 / Mercator 1 or UTM Zone.